How can I make yarn --silent always?
By default, yarn outputs version and timing info every time you run it:
$ yarn 
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.02s.

Is there a better way to stop this pointless noise than putting
alias yarn='yarn --silent'
in my ~/.bashrc?  Ideally, it should also work when yarn is called from a script, and work with NVM.
yarn v4 doesn't even support --silent.
It would be great if there were some global config I could set or, better, if this info was only output if you ran with --verbose, or, even better, never.
On the (extremely rare) occasions when I care about those things, I can do yarn -v or time yarn.  It's completely stupid and annoying to output it every time.  I want clean output that makes it easy to spot anomalies.
